# How to fadeIn element while making a transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/GDj7v/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#field-type").change(function () {
        $val = $(this).val();
        if ($val == "checkbox") {
            $("#check-boxes").addClass("shown");
        } else {
            $("#check-boxes").removeClass("shown");
        }
    })
});
```

Please click on the field type and choose checkbox. My nice transition to show hidden options is working. But I would like to HIDE `#check-boxes` element, so that it would not be so much **white space** between `Field type` and `Description`. I tried `display:none` on the `#check-boxes` element and then in Javascript `fadeIn` and I get very glitchy results.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: You are using opacity which means element still exist on the page and is on the page flow, so it will take space based on your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#check-boxes').hide();
    $("#field-type").change(function() {
        $val    = $(this).val();
        if($val == "checkbox") {
            $('#check-boxes').show(0, function(){
                $("#check-boxes").addClass("shown");
            });
        } else {
            $("#check-boxes").removeClass("shown");
        }
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDj7v/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add this styles:

```
#check-boxes {

  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(250px) rotateX(135deg);
  opacity: 0;
display: none;
}

#check-boxes.shown {

  transform: translateX(0px) rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
    display:block  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has built in methods of fading in/out. For example:

```
//replace $("#check-boxes").addClass("shown"); with
$("#check-boxes").show(400); //fade in 400 ms, essentially the same as jQuery's fadeIn()

//$("#check-boxes").removeClass("shown"); with
$("#check-boxes").hide(400); //fade out 400 ms, essentially the same as jQuery's fadeOut()
```

[Show docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
[Hide docs](http://api.jquery.com/hide)

Also, for custom animations you may want to look into jQuery's `animate` function. Take a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change this by setting the `margin-bottom` property of your `.form-group` nodes to `0`:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` with opacity you can do this way using `animate()`

```
if ($val == "checkbox") {
 $("#check-boxes").css('opacity', 0).slideDown('slow').animate({ opacity: 1 },{duration: 'slow' });
        } else {
$("#check-boxes").css('opacity', 1).slideUp('slow').animate({ opacity: 0 },{duration: 'slow' });
        }
})
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDj7v/21/)

Comment: This is good, but you forgot that I am also using custom transitions that class "show" is giving to my div.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean, I was getting inconsistent results. As you'd expect, [display isn't animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/CSS_animated_properties) which might be the issue when combining transitions with that.
I tried transitioning the height, but that made it look weird.

In the end I used a setTimeout to separate out changing the display property and making the transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/GDj7v/28/

HTML changes:

```
<div id="check-boxes" class="hidden">
```

CSS added:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#field-type").change(function () {

        var $val = $(this).val(),
            checkboxes = $("#check-boxes");

        if ($val === "checkbox") {

            checkboxes.removeClass('hidden');
            setTimeout(function () {
                checkboxes.addClass('shown');
            }, 10);

        } else {

            checkboxes.removeClass('shown');
            setTimeout(function () {
                checkboxes.addClass('hidden');
            }, 1210);

        }

    });

});
```

**EDIT/ALTERNATE SOLUTION**: Also, moving the `transition` property rule into the rules for `#check-boxes.shown` means the transition only happens in one direction, which clears up the issue I was having with height looking bad:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/GDj7v/30/

CSS:

```
#check-boxes {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(250px) rotateX(135deg);
    transform: translateX(250px) rotateX(135deg);
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#check-boxes.shown {
    transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: translateX(0px) rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```